# Why should we preserve the interrupt status when shutting down a Java Executor?

Tags: java, multithreading

On the documentation for [Java's ExecutionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), there's an example method to shut down an executor service and it looks like this:

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
  pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
  try {
    // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
    if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
      pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
      // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
      if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
          System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
    pool.shutdownNow();
    // Preserve interrupt status
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
}
```

What's the purpose of preserving the interrupt status?

Comment: In this specific case or in general? I assume you're asking about the general case.

Comment: @Kayaman: I guess it's the general case. I'm trying to understand that sample code.

Comment: Preserving the interrupt status is advisable generally, not just when shutting down a Java Executor. See, for example, https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html

Answer (score 3):

When you catch the `InterruptedException` the interrupt flag on the current thread is set to false.  So you should set it back to true so that other pieces of code that may be executed under that thread know that the interrupt flag is set, in case they check for it.

Most programmers might not have to check for the interrupt flag, I at least know it is rare in the enterprise code we write.  But for library code it is a good idea to check the interrupt flag before executing any blocking code.  Else the library code might prevent the thread (and possible the application) from shutting down.

So after catching an InterruptedException, it is good form to set the interrupt flag back to true.